# Getting a regression line with a positive slope and a negative Spearman correlation

Tags: python, matplotlib, correlation, scatter-plot

**Update**

I used "scipy.stats.spearmanr" instead of pandas corr function and got a more reasonable results. I used the same input as before. I don't know why pandas corr gave incorrect results. Any ideas?

I'm using matplotlib.pyplot in order to create a scatter plot and a regression line, and pandas series in order to calculate the spearman correlation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as p

# pa is a list of numbers and cai is a pandas series of numbers.

plt.scatter(pa, cai, s=2)
plt.plot(pa, np.poly1d(np.polyfit(pa, cai, 1))(pa), color='red')
plt.text(9, 0.25, f'Spearman R = {round(p.Series(pa).corr(cai, method="spearman"), 3)}')
plt.show()
```

As can be seen in the resulting plot, even though the correlation line has a positive slope, the calculated correlation is negative:

[image: description]

A sample of the input:

```
cai = p.Series([0.414419,0.437525,0.840999,0.552292,0.395373,0.381073,0.416165,0.437319,0.653811,0.495697,0.426237,0.468068,0.416777,0.377957,0.527219,0.418195,0.505802,0.410247,0.457362,0.405840])
pa = [125.0, 736.0, 269000.0, 26300.0, 1920.0, 861.0, 768.0, 1380.0, 38300.0, 16900.0, 967.0, 6800.0, 2780.0, 217.0, 6510.0, 304.0, 606.0, 1170.0, 2210.0, 227.0]
```

I'd be happy to get insights on what might cause the problem.

Comment: It might help to provide a reproducible example with sample data.

Comment: This kind of problem is generally seen in multivariate regression. For example, take a case where height correlates positively with reading ability in children. Consider a more complex case wherein which age is added. Now age predicts reading and the impact of height is negative. I think the problem is multivariate, so a simple regression model is not suitable.

Comment: I think that correlation line you plotted represents Pearsons R not Spearman R, even though in this case even the Spearman rho should probably be positive.